# Writing the Random Matrix model corresponding to any physical hamitonian model

Tags: condensed-matter, spin-models, spin-chains

I am an amateur in Random Matrix Theory (RMT). In RMT, we start with ensemble of a random matrices of a certain symmetry classes (GOE, GUE..) to find the various distribution of our interest, e.g.- spacing distribution, eigenvalue distribution.

My question is: is it allowed/possible to write random matrix model corresponding to given quantum spin model, e,g-one dimensional Heisenberg model : $ H = J \sum \limits_{\langle i,j \rangle} \vec S_i \cdot \vec S_j -g ~\mu_B \sum \limits_{i} \vec S_i \cdot \vec B$, and find the spacing distribution ?

One more Question: Why Randomness in RMT ? or in other words why do we choose random matrices ? could you please explain this one too ?

Many thanks

Comment: To apply RMT you need, as a bare minimum, a set of operators to sample from randomly. What is the set of Hamiltonians you are considering in you Heisenberg example? You seem to have written down a single operator.